# PG11 : how can a user (not owner) create table in a schema without grant create on schema

Tags: postgresql, roles, create-table, privileges, pg

I've been trying for an hour to understand why my odi role, which is neither the owner of the public schema nor the database, can create tables in this schema.

```
          |          | odi=U/eos            |
 public   | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
          |          | =UC/postgres        +|
          |          | odi=U/postgres      +|
          |          | visu=U/postgres      |
```

the most curious thing is that even when I explicitly took away the right (revoke create on schema public from odi), this action didn't stop him from being able to do it.

Any suggestion please?
PG server v11.5
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The reason is this access control item: `=UC/postgres`: it grants `USAGE` and `CREATE` to `PUBLIC` (everybody).

You should remove that insecure default. Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV) says:

> Note that by default, everyone has `CREATE` and `USAGE` privileges on the schema `public`. This allows all users that are able to connect to a given database to create objects in its `public` schema. Some [usage patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS) call for revoking that privilege:
>
> ```
> REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
> ```

Please upgrade at least to the latest minor release (currently, 11.20). Even better, upgrade to v15 or later, because from that version on `PUBLIC` does not have this insecure default permission any more.

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification, I hadn't understood before : An empty grantee field in an aclitem stands for PUBLIC.